# Using Where clause in between Inner Join Query

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I am looking to fetch records and I have come through a scenario in which i have to include additional where clauses between the select query using inner join.

```
select stp.sales_person as "Sales_Person",
max(case when stp.jan_month is null then 0 else stp.jan_month end) as "January",
select sum(so.amount_total) from sale_order so inner join res_users ru on ru.id=so.user_id
where date(so.confirmation_date) > '2017-01-01' and date(so.confirmation_date) < '2017-01-30', 
max(case when stp.feb_month is null then 0 else stp.feb_month end) as "February",   
max(case when stp.march_month is null then 0 else stp.march_month end) as "March",   
max(case when stp.dec_month is null then 0 else stp.dec_month end) as "December"
from sales_target_record stp
inner join res_partner rp on rp.name=stp.sales_person inner join res_users ru on ru.partner_id = rp.id inner join crm_team ct on ru.sale_team_id = ct.id     
where ct.name = 'Direct Sales' group by stp.sales_person
```

I have to insert columns like i tried with `sum` but is not working as its a join query

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> PostgreSQL. Please tag the actual one you are using.

Comment: You don't have an `END` after `so.amount_total` for your `Case` statement

Comment: That `Select` statement has to be enclosed in `()` if you want it as a column.

Comment: but in that scenario the inner join with this particular select will cause problem

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax issue in your query if this is truly SQL Server

```
select 
    stp.sales_person as Sales_Person,
    max(case 
            when stp.jan_month is null 
                then 0 
                else stp.jan_month 
        end) as January,
        --This needed parenthese since it's a subquery. Though, it's uncorrelated
        (   select sum(so.amount_total) 
             from sale_order so 
             inner join res_users ru on ru.id=so.user_id
             where cast(so.confirmation_date as date) > '2017-01-01' and cast(so.confirmation_date as date) < '2017-01-30'
             --here you need to add something like stp.someColumn = so.SomeColumn to correlate it to the outer query
        ) as SomeNewColumnUnCorrelated, 
    max(case 
            when stp.feb_month is null 
                then 0 
                else stp.feb_month 
        end) as February,   
    max(case 
            when stp.march_month is null 
                then 0 
                else stp.march_month 
        end) as March,   
    max(case 
            when stp.dec_month is null 
                then 0
                else stp.dec_month 
        end) as December
from 
    sales_target_record stp
inner join 
    res_partner rp on 
    rp.name=stp.sales_person 
inner join
    res_users ru on 
    ru.partner_id = rp.id     
where 
    ct.name = 'Direct Sales'
group by 
    stp.sales_person
```

Comment: the inner join with `select sum` is fetching wrong record

Comment: I don't doubt it... that's because it's uncorrelated as i stated. You'll have to provide the appropriate where clause for that sub-query. There is no way for us to be certain what that should be

Comment: thats what im asking for sir

Comment: There is no way for us to know the join with our a ERD